# Capistrano not restarting nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have setup Capistrano and eveything is working fine except Capistrano is not restarting passenger after deployment. Eveytime after deployment I have to ssh into server and type `touch tmp/restart.txt` inside `current directory`. I tried different ways to restart passenger but nothing is working for me.

`first attempt:`

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app) do
      run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
    end
  end
end
```

`second attempt`

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app) do
      within current_path do
         execute :touch, 'tmp/restart.txt'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`third attempt`

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end
end
```

I found above code snippets in stackoverflow with similar problem to mine but none of them is restarting the server.

I am using `capistrano (3.4.0)` with `Rails 4` (nginx + passenger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your `deploy:restart` task is not being executed.

Capistrano 3.1.0 and higher (as explained in the [Capistrano's CHANGELOG](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#310)), does not automatically execute `deploy:restart` at the end of `cap deploy`.

You must therefore explicitly tell Capistrano to do so, by adding this to your `deploy.rb`:

```
after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
```

Comment: Hi Matt ya my `deploy:restart` is not being executed. I am going to try your suggestion after work and will keep you updated in the evening. Thanks